# How to access the true RAW request body from post man on a pre-request script?

Tags: postman

I'm trying to authenticate myself against an API. This API uses the raw body from the request to create the hash that it will use to authenticate against my token.

For testing purposes, I'm using postman with a pre request script to create the hash. Everything works fine, with one exception:

In the code tab I have this

[image: request raw body]

however if on the pre request script I dump the value of the request body I get by using request.data I obtain

[image: Postman console output]

The problem is, its not exactly the same string, then the value retrieved by request.data creates a hash with a different body that the server uses to create its hash (the server uses the one beautified with line endings and tabs). This is the script where I use the request body content:

[image: prerequest script]

So unless someone have an idea of how to retrieve the json body exactly on the format it was written, pretty much seems I cant use postman for this

thanks!

Comment: It's very difficult to follow the question - "So unless someone have an idea of how to retreieve the json body exactly on the format" what do you mean by this. Is there a value you want to capture from a different request and use in the body? Does the body need to be sent in JSON?

Comment: nope :), what i want it to use the value from the json request body on the pre-request script, but i need it exactly on the format it has been written on the body tab, not formatted without the line endings and without the tabs (i get it though request.data)

Comment: about your second question, initially i would like to avoid sending it as form rather than json, but i could prefer to leave that solution as last option :)

Comment: Value from the pre-request? You need to update you question with more of these details. You currently have an image of the POST body and an image of the console log but you need one of the pre-request tab and a bit more information. We don't event know what the server implementation is like - Could you not just handle the striping of the data in there?

Comment: added a new screenshot with the header auth creation algorythm

Comment: solved, just reverted my logic. If postman is not able to provide me the body content as on the tab, i have modified the body on the tab to have the same format as the request.data would provide. Not very ortodox but it does do job :), thanks!

Comment: That image of that data dancing between different variables just looks awkward to me. I would look at refactoring some of that. You're also using the new and old syntax to get and set the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just changed the post body tab to 
[new post body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzOlX.png)

and it went just fine. Not really the best solution i was expecting, but does the job :)

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT: I don't know if this existed 5 years ago when the original Question was posted, but it's available in PostMan 8.12.2 at least.*

When you have a request open in Postman, show the "Code" pane at the right by clicking the `</>` button seen in the right-hand toolbar.

[image: screenshot showing where the code button is]

Then in the dropdown header for code type, choose "HTTP".

[image: screenshot showing code generation for HTTP]

The line numbers in the HTTP snippet are significant -- in my screenshot, the last four displayed lines are concatenated into line 6 of the actual HTTP.